# Ganesha Idol Position

Tags: ganesha, idols

I read on the internet that the best position to place The Lord, Ganesha , is at Northeast direction of the house. I found this in other scriptures. Can someone tells me the meaning? Normally Shiva is placed at East and can be related to the rising of the sun.

Comment: Its part of Vastu Shashtra, 9 directions ruled by 9 Gods and 9 planets, NE- Shiva/Jupiter, E-Indra/Sun, SE- Agni/Venus, S - Yama/Mars, SW - Niratti/Rahu, W - Varuna/Saturn, NW - Vayu/Moon, N - Kubera/Mercury, Center- Brahma/Space. Ganesha idol can be placed in NE if there is temple there or house entry.

Comment: Thank You! I was wandering where the direction were mentioned.

Comment: can you please a post answer for reference so we can close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per standard Vedic Vastu Shastra, a rectangular or square house/plot can be divided into 9 blocks corresponding to 9 planets (based on the intensity of Sun shinning on that block corresponding to the timings of days) and are supposed to be used for specific daily functions. Today's westernization and builder's building designer houses for profits and cost-cutting make random designs disregarding ancient spiritual Vastu Shastra rules leading to serious elemental imbalance in the lifestyle of people living within the houses and several mental, emotional disturbances in a family over a period of few years. Like giving entry in south (low walls) leading to direct hot UV rays of afternoon and building high walls in East blocking Sun's beneficial morning rays entering house, making toilets inside house or next to kitchen, making houses on triangular or circular plots, cutting corners,  etc.,

[Vastu Astrology](https://www.astrojyoti.com/vastuastrology.htm)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sun rises in NE/Ishan and sets in SW/Nairutya in circular manner via E, SE, S directions. NE or Ishan is best position for puja room/temple and placement of any God's idol followed by House center's East or House center's West, followed by Centre of House. **If there is a toilet or kitchen or stairs in NE, its a big Vastu Dosha based on the head of Vastu Purusha as puja room cant be made there and is made impure with toilet waste or kitchen's fire or stairs' weight** and may lead to problems like children dropping from school, insomnia, head diseases, headache in one or more of the family members living in the house with such Vastu Dosha.

Comment: also please add the gods to the desceiption 