# Shiv Lingam Position

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

What is the correct orientation of a domestic Shiv Lingam? Where the Yoni should face? Any position is formally allowed or should be positioned for example facing North or South? In this case , can someone document the answer with references?

Comment: The Yoni should face the north. This is is what is followed in Bengal. But some says it can face the east too.

Comment: I read online too

Comment: But are there some references about it?

Comment: Yes there must be some .. will have to check.

Comment: Since water or milk flows through shivling after worship, the water direction is North or North-East corner and is also ruled by Shiva as per Vastu Shastra. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40631/20656 But east is also ok, if north is not possible because of toilet or other issues. Slope of water flowing/draining from a height in the house vastu purusha(a form of Shiva) or Shivlinga should be from SW to NE best, or South to North, West to East good. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT5mzhpiygU

Comment: Read [Page 109, Linga Purana on Worship of Linga](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n113/mode/2up) , See if you can find something useful.

Comment: Have come across some reference that the position of a Shivalinga is mentioned in the Shaiva Agamas. If anyone has a book they may be able to answer

Comment: @Archit thank you, i think that is the way to the final answer..if someone can post it here, will be a useful reference

Comment: Yeah :) You can add an edit to the question saying : is it mentioned in the Shaiva Agamas?

Comment: i will as soon someone will post a complete answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Kamika agama purva pada part one](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/view/kamika-agama-purva-pada-part-1), chapter 4 discusses one of these aspects

> Verse 17: The west facing linga is considered to be superior. If it is
> not available, east facing linga may be used for worship. The north
> facing and south facing lingas are not preferred by Sages for worship.

Chapter 64 is about the installation of Lord Shiva linga in detail. Here the verse 28 clearly states

> One should place the shiva linga along with the pedestal carefully
> with the head portion lying in the east.

Answer (score 1):

In India, the yoni should be facing North. Also, this can depend on many situations like the region of India. One example is that in Rameswaram, the Lingam is facing north, according to this [website](http://www.myrameswaram.com/rameshwaram-temple). Also the lingam in Ekambareshwarar [faces North](https://earth.google.com/web/search/rameshwaram/@12.84861148,79.68153324,85.67992695a,7591.65171232d,35y,-0.00007469h,0.28816473t,0.00000085r/data=CigiJgokCZhcxY38UypAEfI-rWBm-SlAGbggrqGpElRAITQxXMDGB1RA). I have checked the directions and everything, and can say with certainity that the lingam faces North.

Comment: Thank You, but it doesn’t explain why is facing nord and not east. So it is only displaced in that position according by Vastu Shastra? There are no references?

Comment: I think that this [source](https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/shiva-lingam) could be helpful in figuring out the significance of the facing north. Another source that I found on Google Books talked about the north facing part. [Here is the result](https://books.google.com/books?id=7xIrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=why+does+a+lingam+face+north?&source=bl&ots=Mi5iAZvhGj&sig=ACfU3U3zmXV-xNz9qT7CgFmfKa5eeRQiFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrrtq15q7qAhXUop4KHbn0CI0Q6AEwD3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) I hope this helps bring our confusion to an end.

Comment: these link just repeat that should face north, they don’t explain why and neither are scriptural references. The only theory acceptable is the one proposed by Vastu Shastra , but it’s sad not to find any authoritative references.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There are not very many sources about the reason of the lingam facing north.